# performance and flexibility question - how should i categorize my XML files database? using XML or directories?

Tags: c#, performance, flexibility

I am not sure this is the question for this forum.

I am creating a program that uses between 500-1500 files, I would like to know which way is the preferable way to use in-order to categorize my DB.

I am currently categorizing my files from inside the xml files by having a tag:

```
<Category>Basic</Category>
```

this gives me high flexibility of controling the xml files. though it removes a lot of performance, gives me higher space usage, less possibility to create more features (due to low performance).

What i thought i should do is to create a folder called "Basic" (e.g) and store my "Basic" categorized XML files in there - which will give me more performance (etc..) though less flexibility.

should I use folders instead?

Thanks in advanced,

Din.

Comment: Is your performance currently good enough? If not, is the categorization the problem? Will you sort by another dimension than `Category`? What operations will you use? Filter, find, select, aggregate?

Comment: What is your data like? Would it be amenable to using a database, relational or otherwise?  If not, could you keep the categorization information in a database and simply reference the files from there?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: my performance in my opinion isn't pretty good / good enough, i am using only one dimension (category) to sort. I am using XPath to search and get values from inside a XML file (in C# language)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using different file extensions.